# How do I set the screen timeout?

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to set the screen timeout so that the computer
 does not timeout during transfer of a large file.  How do I set the screen timeout?

Comment: You can set the time screen in System Settings -> Brightness and Lock

Comment: For 19,04 its on the power settings screen.

Answer (score 34):

Select the `System Settings` from the icon located on the far right in your top panel. Once there select the `Brightness & Lock` settings. It will look as I've shown below. Change the "Turn screen off when inactive for" to `never`, and change the "Lock Screen" switch to `off`.

[image]

In 18.04 it looks like this...

[image]

Comment: Under 18.04, there is no such setting. It is *Settings > Power > Blank screen* I guess.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not exactly sure what I'm running, but it might help someone else to know that I found it under Settings Manager → Power Manager → Display.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to turn off the screen lock, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
```